# Need to add shortcut in Gvim which will add a string at cursor positions

Tags: vim

I need to develop some shortcuts or inbuilt command in gvim , which will insert "my own required string patterns to the cursor position"

I need to insert some strings like

```
//           ===============================================Start  

or 

//           ===============================================END
```

at the current cursor positions.

Any suggestion , how to proceed ?

Answer (score 2):

#### Built-in abbreviations

That can already be done with the built-in *abbreviations*:

```
:inoreabbrev startmarker //           ===============================================Start
```

Now, every time you type `startmarker`, it is expanded.

#### Built-in mappings

If you prefer to do this from *normal mode*, you can also define mappings:

```
:nnoremap <Leader>sm o//           ===============================================Start<Esc>
```

#### More advanced: snippets

*snippets* are like the built-in `:abbreviate` on steroids, usually with parameter insertions, mirroring, and multiple stops inside them. One of the first, very famous (and still widely used) Vim plugins is [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) (inspired by the *TextMate* editor); unfortunately, it's not maintained any more; though there is [a fork](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate). A modern alternative (that requires Python though) is [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715). There are more, see [this list on the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category%3aAutomated_Text_Insertion).

There are three things to evaluate: First, the features of the snippet engine itself, second, the quality and breadth of snippets provided by the author or others; third, how easy it is to add new snippets.

Answer (score 1):

Try [ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips), it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

add these to your .vimrc:

```
:noremap ,s i // ===============================================Start<esc>
:noremap ,e i // ===============================================END<esc>
```

and use ,s and ,e in view mode to insert text at cursor position